# ASP.Net 4.0 web farm caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, appfabric, web-farm

In ASP.Net 4.0 which is the best way of storing the cache object when we go with webfarm ,

1) Windows Server AppFabric

2) Separate State Machine / SQL Server

3) Thrid party caching mechanisms / Others ?.

Answer (score 4):

I would say sticking with MS technologies would be the best since you're already using ASP.NET. AppFabric was designed just for this case. Otherwise [Memcached](http://memcached.org/) is a good alternative.